# Reshape list/sequence of integers and arrays to array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, reshape

I have multiple lists of format
(count_i, 1dim-array_i)
and I would like to convert them to arrays such that they read

[count_i, 1dim-array_i[0], 1dim-array_i[1], 1dim-array_i[2], ... , 1dim-array_i[n]]

If it helps to understand what I mean, here is an example list:

```
mylist = [[0, array([ 1.        ,  0.73475787,  0.36224658,  0.08579446, -0.11767365,
       -0.09927562,  0.17444341,  0.47212111,  1.00584593,  1.69147789,
        1.89421069,  1.4718292 ])], [2, array([ 1.        ,  0.68744907,  0.38420843,  0.25922927,  0.04719614,
        0.00841919,  0.21967246,  0.22183329,  0.28910002,  0.54637077,
       -0.04389335, -1.33445338])], [3, array([ 1.        ,  0.77854922,  0.41093192,  0.0713814 , -0.08194854,
       -0.07885753,  0.1491798 ,  0.56297583,  1.0759857 ,  1.57149366,
        1.37958867,  0.64409152])], [4, array([ 1.        ,  0.35988801,  0.18939934,  0.45618952,  0.24415997,
       -0.33527807, -0.35296085, -0.41893959, -0.48589674, -0.66222111,
       -0.58601528, -1.14922484])], [5, array([ 1.        ,  0.09182989,  0.14988215, -0.1272845 ,  0.12154707,
       -0.01194815, -0.06136953,  0.18783772,  0.46631855,  0.78850281,
        0.64755372,  0.69757144])]]
```

I have tried (for one of those lists)

```
mylist_sorted = np.ones((len(mylist),len(arrays)+1))
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist_sorted[i] = [i,[mylist[i][1][j] for j in range(len(arrays))]]
```

but this obviously gave me

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension n+1
```

Functions like numpy.reshape didn't help for sequences either...

What's the smartest way to accomplish this?

Many thanks!

Comment: please note: the integer count in this particular list is [0,2,3,4,5], in other lists it will be [2,4,5] or what not. Later in my script I need to call upon those counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Willem's help:

```
mylist_sorted = np.ones((len(mylist),len(arrays)+1))
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist_sorted[i,1:] = mylist[i][1]
    mylist_sorted[i,0] = mylist[i][0]
```

did it!

Answer (score 0):

Your *list comprehension* generates *lists with two elements* where the second one lis a list. For example for `i = 1`, it generates:

```
>>> [i,[mylist[i][1][j] for j in range(12)]]
[1, [1.0, 0.68744907, 0.38420842999999999, 0.25922927000000001, 0.047196139999999998, 0.00841919, 0.21967246000000001, 0.22183328999999999, 0.28910002000000001, 0.54637077000000001, -0.043893349999999998, -1.33445338]]
```

You can however make things easier by writing:

```
mylist_sorted[:,0] = np.arange(len(mylist))
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist_sorted[i,1:] = mylist[i][1]
```

With your sample input, this produces:

```
>>> mylist_sorted
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.73475787,  0.36224658,  0.08579446,
        -0.11767365, -0.09927562,  0.17444341,  0.47212111,  1.00584593,
         1.69147789,  1.89421069,  1.4718292 ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  0.68744907,  0.38420843,  0.25922927,
         0.04719614,  0.00841919,  0.21967246,  0.22183329,  0.28910002,
         0.54637077, -0.04389335, -1.33445338],
       [ 2.        ,  1.        ,  0.77854922,  0.41093192,  0.0713814 ,
        -0.08194854, -0.07885753,  0.1491798 ,  0.56297583,  1.0759857 ,
         1.57149366,  1.37958867,  0.64409152],
       [ 3.        ,  1.        ,  0.35988801,  0.18939934,  0.45618952,
         0.24415997, -0.33527807, -0.35296085, -0.41893959, -0.48589674,
        -0.66222111, -0.58601528, -1.14922484],
       [ 4.        ,  1.        ,  0.09182989,  0.14988215, -0.1272845 ,
         0.12154707, -0.01194815, -0.06136953,  0.18783772,  0.46631855,
         0.78850281,  0.64755372,  0.69757144]])
```

**EDIT**: In case the "counts" are not 0, 1, 2, ... you can alter the above code fragment:

```
for i, (left, right) in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist_sorted[i,0] = left
    mylist_sorted[i,1:] = right
```

Comment: okay, in that case, however, the previous "counts" will now be 0, 1, 2, ..., len(mylist)-1. In my later script, I need the actual counts tho. In this example: 0, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: with your help,
    peak_corr_cell01_BR_sorted = np.ones((len(peak_corr_cell01_BR),len(corr_mean)+1))
    for i in range(len(peak_corr_cell01_BR)):
        peak_corr_cell01_BR_sorted[i,1:] = peak_corr_cell01_BR[i][1]
        peak_corr_cell01_BR_sorted[i,0] = peak_corr_cell01_BR[i][0]
did it!